# SQL: get DATEDIFF to not return negative values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, datediff

I have a query in which I am pulling the runtime of an executable. The database contains its start time and its end time. I would like to get the total time for the run.
So far I have:

```
SELECT startTime, endTime,
cast(datediff(hh,starttime,endtime) as varchar)
+':'
+cast(datediff(mi,starttime,endtime)-60*datediff(hh,starttime,endtime) as varchar) AS RUNTIME
FROM applog
WHERE runID = 33871
ORDER BY startTime DESC
```

When I execute this I get expected values and also some unexpected.
For example, if starttime = 2008-11-02 15:59:59.790 and endtime = 2008-11-02 19:05:41.857 then the runtime is = 4:-54.
How do I get a quere in MS SQL SMS to return the value 3:06 for this case?

Thanks.

Eoin Campbell's I selected as the answer is the most bulletproof for my needs. David B's is do-able as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these

Assuming 2 declared dates.

```
declare @start datetime
set @start = '2008-11-02 15:59:59.790'

declare @end datetime
set @end = '2008-11-02 19:05:41.857'
```

This will return the hours / mins / seconds

```
select 
    (datediff(ss, @start, @end) / 3600), 
    (datediff(ss, @start, @end) / 60) % 60,
    (datediff(ss, @start, @end) % 60) % 60

--returns

----------- ----------- -----------
3           5           42
```

This is the zero-padded concatenated string version

```
select
RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(nvarchar, (datediff(ss, @start, @end) / 3600)), 2) + ':' +
RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(nvarchar, (datediff(ss, @start, @end) / 60) % 60), 2) + ':' +
RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(nvarchar, (datediff(ss, @start, @end) % 60) % 60), 2)

--------
03:05:42
```

Comment: I tried the above code for a requirement I had and the problem is when my start time is greater than end time. The negative value only comes for minutes. For example, assume start time is 07:31:01 and end time is 07:30:03 and the result is coming as 00:00:58 which they are saying should be -58. Can we get it as 00:00:-58?

Comment: I tried the below code :  CONVERT(NVARCHAR, (Datediff(ss, raa.schedtime, 
            raa.actualtime) / 
         3600), 2) 
         + ':' 
         + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, (Datediff(ss, raa.schedtime, 
            raa.actualtime) / 
         60) % 60, 2) 
         + ':' 
         + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, (Datediff(ss, raa.schedtime, 
            raa.actualtime) % 
         60) % 60, 2)   This gets me the result 0:0:-58 but as you see its not hh:mm:ss format

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2008/04/find-hours-minutes-and-seconds-in.html) a way to do it:

```
-- Find Hours, Minutes and Seconds in between two datetime
DECLARE @First datetime
DECLARE @Second datetime
SET @First = '04/02/2008 05:23:22'
SET @Second = getdate()

SELECT DATEDIFF(day,@First,@Second)*24 as TotalHours,
DATEDIFF(day,@First,@Second)*24*60 as TotalMinutes,
DATEDIFF(day,@First,@Second)*24*60*60 as TotalSeconds
```

Comment: That works great if you are thinking in terms of calendar dates, but all those answers are in "day-sized" chunks.  3:06 is clearly not a day-sized chunk.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be consistent with your calls to datediff(). They should all use the same datepart argument.

See [MSDN's DATEDIFF (Transact-SQL) article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx).

In your example, you're using both "mi" and "hh" and concatenating.

Choose the least common denominator for your durations (probably ss or s) and do any math based on that (as the other answers are illustrating, but not really describing).

Answer (score 0):

You should separate your calculation and presentation logic:

```
DECLARE @applog TABLE
(
  runID int,
  starttime datetime,
  endtime datetime
)

INSERT INTO @applog (runID, starttime, endtime)
SELECT 33871, '2008-11-02 15:59:59.790', '2008-11-02 19:05:41.857'
-------------------
SELECT
  SUBSTRING(convert(varchar(30), DateAdd(mi, duration, 0), 121),
  12, 5) as prettyduration
FROM
(
SELECT starttime, DateDiff(mi, starttime, endtime) as duration
FROM @applog
WHERE runID = 33871
) as sub
```

If you need to represent more than 24 hours, you would use a different presentation logic.  This is just what I could think of fastest.